# OAuth, node-fetch and twitter API

Tags: node.js, express, http, twitter, oauth

Using the the [twitter package for node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) I am able to make requests to the twitter API endpoint `.../statuses/user_timeline.json` with my access token and consumer keys/secrets.

**What I want to do**

In order to understand OAuth and the basic http request response system, I am trying to recreate the authorization done by the twitter node package and make a node-fetch request.

**What I get**

I always get the same 401 Authorization Required response from twitter. I can't figure out what's wrong with my authorization token. Maybe it's something very wrong with my fetch request?

**What I did**

Following the description on the [twitter developer page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/authorizing-a-request) I wrote the function below to calculate the authorization string. Using the steps described on [this twitter page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature) my function returns the same OAuth signature, when given the exact same values for the parameters.

```
//twitter.js
const crypto = require('crypto')
module.exports = function(method, url){
    const twitter = {
        oauth_consumer_key      : process.env.TWITTER_KEY,
        oauth_token             : process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        oauth_nonce             : crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex'),
        oauth_timestamp         : Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
        oauth_signature_method  : 'HMAC-SHA1',
        oauth_version           : '1.0'
    }

    const methodWord     = method.toUpperCase();
    let parameter_string = ''

    Object.keys(twitter).sort().forEach(key => {
        parameter_string += key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(twitter[key]) + '&'
    })

    parameter_string = parameter_string.slice(0, -1)//remove last &
    parameter_string = parameter_string.replace(/!/g, '%21')//replace !'s

    const hmacDigest = crypto.createHmac('sha1', 
        encodeURIComponent(process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET) + '&' 
      + encodeURIComponent(process.env.TWITTER_TOKEN_SECRET))

    hmacDigest.update(
        methodWord + '&' 
      + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&' 
      + encodeURIComponent(parameter_string))

    twitter['oauth_signature'] = hmacDigest.digest('base64')
    let authHeader             = 'OAuth '

    Object.keys(twitter).sort().forEach(key => {
        authHeader += key + '="' + encodeURIComponent(twitter[key]) + '", '
    })
    return authHeader.slice(0, -2)//remove last comma and space, and return
}
```

The returned authentication token is then used for a node-fetch GET request on my express server

```
//server.js
const twitterAuth = require('./twitter')
const twitter_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'
app.get('/api/twitter', (req, res) => {
    const auth = twitterAuth('GET', twitter_url + '?screen_name=<user_name>')
    fetch(twitter_url + '?screen_name=<user_name>', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type'  : 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : auth
        }   
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsonRes => res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(jsonRes)))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error: ',err)
        res.status(500).send(err)
    })
})
```

Comment: Hey Michael, if I read the Twitter documentation correctly, you are first of all supposed to add those oauth key values to the url as parameters. I think you forgot about that.

Comment: I think the url is only needed for the `oauth_signature`. This is a string containing the method, url and the parameters, which is then hashed by using sha1 and the key and token secrets. I did that in the line

`hmacDigest.update(
        methodWord + '&' 
      + encodeURIComponent(**url**) + '&' 
      + encodeURIComponent(parameter_string))`